# Resolving a DNS name to an IPAddress... Which one of the many IPs should I pick?

Tags: .net, networking, dns, ip

It's straight forward to resolve a host name to IP addresses:

```
foreach (var hostName in new [] { "github.com", "microsoft.com", "google.com", "stackoverflow.com" })
{
    var ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);

    Console.WriteLine($"=== {hostName}");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ipAddresses.Select(ip => ip.ToString())));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

[image]

If I now want to **select a single IP address** to make a connection (and log that exact IP address), how would I select it?

Complications:

1. There can be multiple IP addresses.
2. There can be multiple address families (IPv4 vs. IPv6).
3. IPv6 addresses might be returned but the system might not support IPv6.

Is there an accepted or recommended way to chose one?

Comment: Can someone comment why this is too broad or an unworthy question? It seems very concrete and practical.

Comment: That depends on the protocol but typically, you should try all of them in order (the library you use should give them in "proper" order locally), and stop when one works as expected. You can also apply "happy eyeball" protocol in the face of IPv4+IPv6: you want to favor IPv6 because you are a good netizen but do not wait on it timeouing so in broad term you try to connect to both IPs, giving slightly better change to IPv6 by starting it first, and you pick first one that works. Makes code more complicated, but users happier and technical guys too as you default on IPv6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my research I found the following relevant aspects:

1. Some sources recommend using the IP addresses in the order that is returned by the resolver and the OS.
2. That way clever DNS solutions can be developed that load balance based on the client IP but that also allow the client to fail over to a more remote IP.
3. The client can just pick the first IP if no redundancy is needed. This can be dangerous if an IPv6 address is returned first but IPv6 is not supported. Web sources say that many unsophisticated clients use this approach.
4. The client can try the addresses in order for redundancy. Management of timeouts becomes more important here. Apparently, browsers do this.
5. Depending on whether IPv4 and/or IPv6 are supported it makes sense to filter out addresses of an unsupported address family.
6. Patrick Mevzek suggested giving preference to IPv6 where supported to help adoption of IPv6.
7. Sometimes it cannot be determined whether IPv6 is available or not except by trying to connect. In order to minimize connect latency the application can connect using IPv4 and IPv6 in parallel. This is called [Happy Eyeballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Eyeballs).

The .NET Framework implements the following algorithm in `Socket.Connect(string hostName, int port)`: It resolves all IP addresses, filters out unsupported address families and tries to connect to them in order. This algorithm seems best to me. `TcpClient.Connect(string hostName, int port)` does something similar that I cannot quite decipher.

Comment: "Some sources recommend using the IP addresses in the order that is returned by the resolver and the OS." Yes, the application should take into account the order because, for example on Linux systems with `/etc/gai.conf`, the OS can order things based on local criteria. Note however that at the DNS level, it is a set, not a list, and that typically resolver retuns the records in different order (typically round robin) at each query.

Comment: "This can be dangerous if an IPv6 address is returned first but IPv6 is not supported." when an application requests data to the OS it can ask for just A or just AAAA or both. So if the application does not want IPv6 it should not ask for AAAA. Also, at the OS level, see above, results can be configured with /etc/gai.conf or equivalent. You also have the "happy eyeballs" algorithms to deal with IPv6/IPv4 issues.

Answer (score 0):

This will select the first IP address for each host.

```
foreach (var hostName in new[] { "github.com", "microsoft.com", "google.com", "stackoverflow.com" })
{
    var ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);

    Console.WriteLine($"=== {hostName}");
    Console.WriteLine(ipAddresses.FirstOrDefault());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: But is that the correct address to chose? Why not the others?

Comment: It's the first address returned from your DNS subsystem. I'm not sure what you mean with "the correct address", in order to determine that you must first specify rules for "correct address".

Comment: I want to know the rules because I do not know them. Is there really no significance to which IP to chose? Does it not matter? Could we pick a random one? There must be some guidance.

Comment: Different hosts have different reasons for having multiple ip's. The most common reason is probably is to redirect traffic in case the primary IP goes down. If you want to build really resilient code, you could fallback to the next IP if the first one in the list doesn't produce the results you expected.